# How do I suppress a window background paint in XLib?

Tags: x11, repaint, xlib, flicker

I'm new to X and Linux programming in general. It's pretty easy to suppress a window background repaint (to reduce flicker when the window is resized) using VC++ and Windows. However the architecture and difficulty in finding comprehensive documentation for X is a different game altogether.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `pixmap` which will serve as an offscreen temporary buffer, draw into it, and after all drawing operations have been completed update the window background only once:

```
Pixmap pixmap = XCreatePixmap(display,
                              rootWindow,
                              width,
                              height,
                              XDefaultDepthOfScreen(screen));
// Draw into pixmap
// ...
// ...
// And update window background after that
XSetWindowBackgroundPixmap(display, window, pixmap);
XClearWindow(display, window);
```